# Hyperlinks are randomly clickable

Tags: html, css

Help. I just upgraded my website so that it's mobile-friendly. Now a lot of links don't work. In fact, the very same link will work in one place on the page (the menu), but then not work elsewhere on the same page. I seem to have numerous links throughout the site that don't work even though the code looks right. Even when I put in absolute coding, it still isn't clickable.  I would appreciate any help. 
 Thanks. This is my home page: http://hotsermons.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've added some `divs` on links, So when you hover on the link, you actually hover on this `div` not the link.
To solve this make sure you're using `position` and `z-index` properties correctly.

Comment: Thanks Zeyad. I'm not sure how that works as I'm very basic at coding. Here is the first link on my page that doesn't work: <h2><a href="topical-sermon-outlines-series.html" title="Topical Sermon Outlines - Series" target="_self" >Topical Sermon Outlines - Series</a></h2>  There is no div there, so I'm not quite sure what you mean. As far as I can see there are numerous links throughout my site that are unclickable and none of them use a div. Have I misunderstood what you mean?

Comment: Your mistake isn't in html code, you made some divs appear on(overly) these hyperlinks in your css file. So when you click on hyperlinks, the cursor actually be on those divs. To solve this make sure that the divs in correct position.

Comment: Thanks Zeyad. At this point I've re-uploaded the old site. I'm a long way from being an expert on this. The template I used was one I downloaded from templated.co and then I changed what I needed to suit. That being the case, I haven't changed anything in the css file. My confusion is that, although all the menu links work well (that's where all the divs are!), the links I'm having problems with are in the main body of the content. And it's just random. One link works, the next one doesn't. And I've checked them all several times. Could you please explain how the css divs would affect this?

Comment: Ok. Replace your code:
`#rightside{margin-top: 0;}`
`#content{display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
    grid-column-gap: 15px;
    grid-template-areas: "leftside rightside" "footer footer";}`
`#footer{grid-area: footer;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 5px auto;}`
[screenshot](https://ibb.co/cWqduH)